# GAN generator producing distinguishable output

Tags: machine-learning, keras, deep-learning, generative-adversarial-network

I am trying to train a special type of GAN called a Model-Assisted GAN (https://arxiv.org/pdf/1812.00879) using Keras, which takes as an input a vector of 13 input parameters + Gaussian noise, and generate a vector of 6 outputs. The mapping between the vectors of inputs and outputs is non-trivial, as it is related to a high energy physics simulation (in particular the simulation has some inherent randomness). The biggest dependence on the final outputs are encoded in the first five inputs. The biggest difference for this model to a traditional GAN is the use of a Siamese network as the discriminator, and this takes two inputs at a time, so for the same input parameters we provide two sets of possible outputs per training (possible due to the randomness of the simulation), so there are sort of 12 output distributions, but only 6 are unique, which is what we aim to generate. We used a 1D convolutional neural network for both the discriminator and generator.

The current model we have trained seems to reproduce the output distributions for an independent testing sample to reasonably good accuracy (see below plot of histograms overlayed), but there are still some clear differences between the distributions, and the eventual goal is for the model to be able to produce indistinguishable data to the simulation. I have so far tried varying the learning rate and added varying amounts of learning rate decay, tweaking the network architectures, changing some of the hyperparameters of the optimiser, adding some more noise to the discriminator training by implementing some label smoothing and swapping the order of inputs, adding some label smoothing to the generator training, increasing the batch size and also increasing the amount of noise inputs, and I still cannot get the model to perfectly reproduce the output distributions. I am struggling to come up with ideas of what to do next, and I was wondering if anyone else has had a similar problem, whereby the output is not quite perfect, and if so how they might have gone about solving this problem? Any thoughts or tips would be greatly appreciated!

I have included the full code for the training, as well as some plots of the input and output distributions (before applying the Quantile Transformer), the loss plots for the adversarial network and the discriminator (A for Adversarial, S for Siamese (Discriminator)) and then the overlay of the histograms for the generated and true output distributions for the independent testing sample (which is where you can see the small differences that arise).

Thanks in advance.

TRAINING CODE

```
"""
Training implementation
"""

net_range = [-1,1]
gauss_range = [-5.5,5.5]

mapping = interp1d(gauss_range, net_range)

class ModelAssistedGANPID(object):

    def __init__(self, params=64, observables=6):
        self.params = params
        self.observables = observables
        self.Networks = Networks(params=params, observables=observables)
        self.siamese = self.Networks.siamese_model()
        self.adversarial1 = self.Networks.adversarial1_model()

    def train(self, pretrain_steps=4500, train_steps=100000, batch_size=32, train_no=1):

        print('Pretraining for ', pretrain_steps,' steps before training for ', train_steps, ' steps')
        print('Batch size = ', batch_size)
        print('Training number = ', train_no)

        '''
        Pre-training stage
        '''
        # Number of tracks for the training + validation sample
        n_events = 1728000 + 100000
        n_train = n_events - 100000

        # Parameters for Gaussian noise
        lower = -1
        upper = 1
        mu = 0
        sigma = 1

        # import simulation data

        print('Loading data...')

        kaon_data = pd.read_hdf('PATH')

        kaon_data = kaon_data.sample(n=n_events)
        kaon_data = kaon_data.reset_index(drop=True)

        kaon_data_train = kaon_data[:n_train]
        kaon_data_test = kaon_data[n_train:n_events]

        print("Producing training data...")

        # add all inputs

        P_kaon_data_train = kaon_data_train['TrackP']
        Pt_kaon_data_train = kaon_data_train['TrackPt']
        nTracks_kaon_data_train = kaon_data_train['NumLongTracks']
        numRich1_kaon_data_train = kaon_data_train['NumRich1Hits']
        numRich2_kaon_data_train = kaon_data_train['NumRich2Hits']
        rich1EntryX_kaon_data_train = kaon_data_train['TrackRich1EntryX']
        rich1EntryY_kaon_data_train = kaon_data_train['TrackRich1EntryY']
        rich1ExitX_kaon_data_train = kaon_data_train['TrackRich1ExitX']
        rich1ExitY_kaon_data_train = kaon_data_train['TrackRich1ExitY']
        rich2EntryX_kaon_data_train = kaon_data_train['TrackRich2EntryX']
        rich2EntryY_kaon_data_train = kaon_data_train['TrackRich2EntryY']
        rich2ExitX_kaon_data_train = kaon_data_train['TrackRich2ExitX']
        rich2ExitY_kaon_data_train = kaon_data_train['TrackRich2ExitY']

        # add different DLL outputs

        Dlle_kaon_data_train = kaon_data_train['RichDLLe']
        Dlle2_kaon_data_train = kaon_data_train['RichDLLe2']
        Dllmu_kaon_data_train = kaon_data_train['RichDLLmu']
        Dllmu2_kaon_data_train = kaon_data_train['RichDLLmu2']
        Dllk_kaon_data_train = kaon_data_train['RichDLLk']
        Dllk2_kaon_data_train = kaon_data_train['RichDLLk2']
        Dllp_kaon_data_train = kaon_data_train['RichDLLp']
        Dllp2_kaon_data_train = kaon_data_train['RichDLLp2']
        Dlld_kaon_data_train = kaon_data_train['RichDLLd']
        Dlld2_kaon_data_train = kaon_data_train['RichDLLd2']
        Dllbt_kaon_data_train = kaon_data_train['RichDLLbt']
        Dllbt2_kaon_data_train = kaon_data_train['RichDLLbt2']

        # convert to numpy array

        P_kaon_data_train = P_kaon_data_train.to_numpy()
        Pt_kaon_data_train = Pt_kaon_data_train.to_numpy()
        nTracks_kaon_data_train = nTracks_kaon_data_train.to_numpy()
        numRich1_kaon_data_train = numRich1_kaon_data_train.to_numpy()
        numRich2_kaon_data_train = numRich2_kaon_data_train.to_numpy()
        rich1EntryX_kaon_data_train = rich1EntryX_kaon_data_train.to_numpy()
        rich1EntryY_kaon_data_train = rich1EntryY_kaon_data_train.to_numpy()
        rich1ExitX_kaon_data_train = rich1ExitX_kaon_data_train.to_numpy()
        rich1ExitY_kaon_data_train = rich1ExitY_kaon_data_train.to_numpy()
        rich2EntryX_kaon_data_train = rich2EntryX_kaon_data_train.to_numpy()
        rich2EntryY_kaon_data_train = rich2EntryY_kaon_data_train.to_numpy()
        rich2ExitX_kaon_data_train = rich2ExitX_kaon_data_train.to_numpy()
        rich2ExitY_kaon_data_train = rich2ExitY_kaon_data_train.to_numpy()

        Dlle_kaon_data_train = Dlle_kaon_data_train.to_numpy()
        Dlle2_kaon_data_train = Dlle2_kaon_data_train.to_numpy()
        Dllmu_kaon_data_train = Dllmu_kaon_data_train.to_numpy()
        Dllmu2_kaon_data_train = Dllmu2_kaon_data_train.to_numpy()
        Dllk_kaon_data_train = Dllk_kaon_data_train.to_numpy()
        Dllk2_kaon_data_train = Dllk2_kaon_data_train.to_numpy()
        Dllp_kaon_data_train = Dllp_kaon_data_train.to_numpy()
        Dllp2_kaon_data_train = Dllp2_kaon_data_train.to_numpy()
        Dlld_kaon_data_train = Dlld_kaon_data_train.to_numpy()
        Dlld2_kaon_data_train = Dlld2_kaon_data_train.to_numpy()
        Dllbt_kaon_data_train = Dllbt_kaon_data_train.to_numpy()
        Dllbt2_kaon_data_train = Dllbt2_kaon_data_train.to_numpy()

        # Reshape arrays

        P_kaon_data_train = np.array(P_kaon_data_train).reshape(-1, 1)
        Pt_kaon_data_train = np.array(Pt_kaon_data_train).reshape(-1, 1)
        nTracks_kaon_data_train = np.array(nTracks_kaon_data_train).reshape(-1, 1)
        numRich1_kaon_data_train = np.array(numRich1_kaon_data_train).reshape(-1, 1)
        numRich2_kaon_data_train = np.array(numRich2_kaon_data_train).reshape(-1, 1)
        rich1EntryX_kaon_data_train = np.array(rich1EntryX_kaon_data_train).reshape(-1, 1)
        rich1EntryY_kaon_data_train = np.array(rich1EntryY_kaon_data_train).reshape(-1, 1)
        rich1ExitX_kaon_data_train = np.array(rich1ExitX_kaon_data_train).reshape(-1, 1)
        rich1ExitY_kaon_data_train = np.array(rich1ExitY_kaon_data_train).reshape(-1, 1)
        rich2EntryX_kaon_data_train = np.array(rich2EntryX_kaon_data_train).reshape(-1, 1)
        rich2EntryY_kaon_data_train = np.array(rich2EntryY_kaon_data_train).reshape(-1, 1)
        rich2ExitX_kaon_data_train = np.array(rich2ExitX_kaon_data_train).reshape(-1, 1)
        rich2ExitY_kaon_data_train = np.array(rich2ExitY_kaon_data_train).reshape(-1, 1)

        Dlle_kaon_data_train = np.array(Dlle_kaon_data_train).reshape(-1, 1)
        Dlle2_kaon_data_train = np.array(Dlle2_kaon_data_train).reshape(-1, 1)
        Dllmu_kaon_data_train = np.array(Dllmu_kaon_data_train).reshape(-1, 1)
        Dllmu2_kaon_data_train = np.array(Dllmu2_kaon_data_train).reshape(-1, 1)
        Dllk_kaon_data_train = np.array(Dllk_kaon_data_train).reshape(-1, 1)
        Dllk2_kaon_data_train = np.array(Dllk2_kaon_data_train).reshape(-1, 1)
        Dllp_kaon_data_train = np.array(Dllp_kaon_data_train).reshape(-1, 1)
        Dllp2_kaon_data_train = np.array(Dllp2_kaon_data_train).reshape(-1, 1)
        Dlld_kaon_data_train = np.array(Dlld_kaon_data_train).reshape(-1, 1)
        Dlld2_kaon_data_train = np.array(Dlld2_kaon_data_train).reshape(-1, 1)
        Dllbt_kaon_data_train = np.array(Dllbt_kaon_data_train).reshape(-1, 1)
        Dllbt2_kaon_data_train = np.array(Dllbt2_kaon_data_train).reshape(-1, 1)

        inputs_kaon_data_train = np.concatenate((P_kaon_data_train, Pt_kaon_data_train, nTracks_kaon_data_train, numRich1_kaon_data_train, numRich2_kaon_data_train, rich1EntryX_kaon_data_train, 
        rich1EntryY_kaon_data_train, rich1ExitX_kaon_data_train, rich1ExitY_kaon_data_train, rich2EntryX_kaon_data_train, rich2EntryY_kaon_data_train, rich2ExitX_kaon_data_train, rich2ExitY_kaon_data_train), axis=1)
        Dll_kaon_data_train = np.concatenate((Dlle_kaon_data_train, Dllmu_kaon_data_train, Dllk_kaon_data_train, Dllp_kaon_data_train, Dlld_kaon_data_train, Dllbt_kaon_data_train), axis=1)
        Dll2_kaon_data_train = np.concatenate((Dlle2_kaon_data_train, Dllmu2_kaon_data_train, Dllk2_kaon_data_train, Dllp2_kaon_data_train, Dlld2_kaon_data_train, Dllbt2_kaon_data_train), axis=1)

        print('Transforming inputs and outputs using Quantile Transformer...')

        scaler_inputs = QuantileTransformer(output_distribution='normal', n_quantiles=int(1e5), subsample=int(1e10)).fit(inputs_kaon_data_train)
        scaler_Dll = QuantileTransformer(output_distribution='normal', n_quantiles=int(1e5), subsample=int(1e10)).fit(Dll_kaon_data_train)
        scaler_Dll2 = QuantileTransformer(output_distribution='normal', n_quantiles=int(1e5), subsample=int(1e10)).fit(Dll2_kaon_data_train)

        inputs_kaon_data_train = scaler_inputs.transform(inputs_kaon_data_train)
        Dll_kaon_data_train = scaler_Dll.transform(Dll_kaon_data_train)
        Dll2_kaon_data_train = scaler_Dll2.transform(Dll2_kaon_data_train)

        inputs_kaon_data_train = mapping(inputs_kaon_data_train)
        Dll_kaon_data_train = mapping(Dll_kaon_data_train)
        Dll2_kaon_data_train = mapping(Dll2_kaon_data_train)

        # REPEATING FOR TESTING DATA

        print("Producing testing data...")

        # add all inputs

        P_kaon_data_test = kaon_data_test['TrackP']
        Pt_kaon_data_test = kaon_data_test['TrackPt']
        nTracks_kaon_data_test = kaon_data_test['NumLongTracks']
        numRich1_kaon_data_test = kaon_data_test['NumRich1Hits']
        numRich2_kaon_data_test = kaon_data_test['NumRich2Hits']
        rich1EntryX_kaon_data_test = kaon_data_test['TrackRich1EntryX']
        rich1EntryY_kaon_data_test = kaon_data_test['TrackRich1EntryY']
        rich1ExitX_kaon_data_test = kaon_data_test['TrackRich1ExitX']
        rich1ExitY_kaon_data_test = kaon_data_test['TrackRich1ExitY']
        rich2EntryX_kaon_data_test = kaon_data_test['TrackRich2EntryX']
        rich2EntryY_kaon_data_test = kaon_data_test['TrackRich2EntryY']
        rich2ExitX_kaon_data_test = kaon_data_test['TrackRich2ExitX']
        rich2ExitY_kaon_data_test = kaon_data_test['TrackRich2ExitY']

        # add different DLL outputs

        Dlle_kaon_data_test = kaon_data_test['RichDLLe']
        Dlle2_kaon_data_test = kaon_data_test['RichDLLe2']
        Dllmu_kaon_data_test = kaon_data_test['RichDLLmu']
        Dllmu2_kaon_data_test = kaon_data_test['RichDLLmu2']
        Dllk_kaon_data_test = kaon_data_test['RichDLLk']
        Dllk2_kaon_data_test = kaon_data_test['RichDLLk2']
        Dllp_kaon_data_test = kaon_data_test['RichDLLp']
        Dllp2_kaon_data_test = kaon_data_test['RichDLLp2']
        Dlld_kaon_data_test = kaon_data_test['RichDLLd']
        Dlld2_kaon_data_test = kaon_data_test['RichDLLd2']
        Dllbt_kaon_data_test = kaon_data_test['RichDLLbt']
        Dllbt2_kaon_data_test = kaon_data_test['RichDLLbt2']

        # convert to numpy array

        P_kaon_data_test = P_kaon_data_test.to_numpy()
        Pt_kaon_data_test = Pt_kaon_data_test.to_numpy()
        nTracks_kaon_data_test = nTracks_kaon_data_test.to_numpy()
        numRich1_kaon_data_test = numRich1_kaon_data_test.to_numpy()
        numRich2_kaon_data_test = numRich2_kaon_data_test.to_numpy()
        rich1EntryX_kaon_data_test = rich1EntryX_kaon_data_test.to_numpy()
        rich1EntryY_kaon_data_test = rich1EntryY_kaon_data_test.to_numpy()
        rich1ExitX_kaon_data_test = rich1ExitX_kaon_data_test.to_numpy()
        rich1ExitY_kaon_data_test = rich1ExitY_kaon_data_test.to_numpy()
        rich2EntryX_kaon_data_test = rich2EntryX_kaon_data_test.to_numpy()
        rich2EntryY_kaon_data_test = rich2EntryY_kaon_data_test.to_numpy()
        rich2ExitX_kaon_data_test = rich2ExitX_kaon_data_test.to_numpy()
        rich2ExitY_kaon_data_test = rich2ExitY_kaon_data_test.to_numpy()
        Dlle_kaon_data_test = Dlle_kaon_data_test.to_numpy()
        Dlle2_kaon_data_test = Dlle2_kaon_data_test.to_numpy()
        Dllmu_kaon_data_test = Dllmu_kaon_data_test.to_numpy()
        Dllmu2_kaon_data_test = Dllmu2_kaon_data_test.to_numpy()
        Dllk_kaon_data_test = Dllk_kaon_data_test.to_numpy()
        Dllk2_kaon_data_test = Dllk2_kaon_data_test.to_numpy()
        Dllp_kaon_data_test = Dllp_kaon_data_test.to_numpy()
        Dllp2_kaon_data_test = Dllp2_kaon_data_test.to_numpy()
        Dlld_kaon_data_test = Dlld_kaon_data_test.to_numpy()
        Dlld2_kaon_data_test = Dlld2_kaon_data_test.to_numpy()
        Dllbt_kaon_data_test = Dllbt_kaon_data_test.to_numpy()
        Dllbt2_kaon_data_test = Dllbt2_kaon_data_test.to_numpy()

        P_kaon_data_test = np.array(P_kaon_data_test).reshape(-1, 1)
        Pt_kaon_data_test = np.array(Pt_kaon_data_test).reshape(-1, 1)
        nTracks_kaon_data_test = np.array(nTracks_kaon_data_test).reshape(-1, 1)
        numRich1_kaon_data_test = np.array(numRich1_kaon_data_test).reshape(-1, 1)
        numRich2_kaon_data_test = np.array(numRich2_kaon_data_test).reshape(-1, 1)
        rich1EntryX_kaon_data_test = np.array(rich1EntryX_kaon_data_test).reshape(-1, 1)
        rich1EntryY_kaon_data_test = np.array(rich1EntryY_kaon_data_test).reshape(-1, 1)
        rich1ExitX_kaon_data_test = np.array(rich1ExitX_kaon_data_test).reshape(-1, 1)
        rich1ExitY_kaon_data_test = np.array(rich1ExitY_kaon_data_test).reshape(-1, 1)
        rich2EntryX_kaon_data_test = np.array(rich2EntryX_kaon_data_test).reshape(-1, 1)
        rich2EntryY_kaon_data_test = np.array(rich2EntryY_kaon_data_test).reshape(-1, 1)
        rich2ExitX_kaon_data_test = np.array(rich2ExitX_kaon_data_test).reshape(-1, 1)
        rich2ExitY_kaon_data_test = np.array(rich2ExitY_kaon_data_test).reshape(-1, 1)
        Dlle_kaon_data_test = np.array(Dlle_kaon_data_test).reshape(-1, 1)
        Dlle2_kaon_data_test = np.array(Dlle2_kaon_data_test).reshape(-1, 1)
        Dllmu_kaon_data_test = np.array(Dllmu_kaon_data_test).reshape(-1, 1)
        Dllmu2_kaon_data_test = np.array(Dllmu2_kaon_data_test).reshape(-1, 1)
        Dllk_kaon_data_test = np.array(Dllk_kaon_data_test).reshape(-1, 1)
        Dllk2_kaon_data_test = np.array(Dllk2_kaon_data_test).reshape(-1, 1)
        Dllp_kaon_data_test = np.array(Dllp_kaon_data_test).reshape(-1, 1)
        Dllp2_kaon_data_test = np.array(Dllp2_kaon_data_test).reshape(-1, 1)
        Dlld_kaon_data_test = np.array(Dlld_kaon_data_test).reshape(-1, 1)
        Dlld2_kaon_data_test = np.array(Dlld2_kaon_data_test).reshape(-1, 1)
        Dllbt_kaon_data_test = np.array(Dllbt_kaon_data_test).reshape(-1, 1)
        Dllbt2_kaon_data_test = np.array(Dllbt2_kaon_data_test).reshape(-1, 1)

        inputs_kaon_data_test = np.concatenate((P_kaon_data_test, Pt_kaon_data_test, nTracks_kaon_data_test, numRich1_kaon_data_test, numRich2_kaon_data_test, rich1EntryX_kaon_data_test, rich1EntryY_kaon_data_test, rich1ExitX_kaon_data_test, rich1ExitY_kaon_data_test, rich2EntryX_kaon_data_test, rich2EntryY_kaon_data_test, rich2ExitX_kaon_data_test, rich2ExitY_kaon_data_test), axis=1)
        Dll_kaon_data_test = np.concatenate((Dlle_kaon_data_test, Dllmu_kaon_data_test, Dllk_kaon_data_test, Dllp_kaon_data_test, Dlld_kaon_data_test, Dllbt_kaon_data_test), axis=1)
        Dll2_kaon_data_test = np.concatenate((Dlle2_kaon_data_test, Dllmu2_kaon_data_test, Dllk2_kaon_data_test, Dllp2_kaon_data_test, Dlld2_kaon_data_test, Dllbt2_kaon_data_test), axis=1)

        print('Transforming inputs and outputs using Quantile Transformer...')

        inputs_kaon_data_test = scaler_inputs.transform(inputs_kaon_data_test)
        Dll_kaon_data_test = scaler_Dll.transform(Dll_kaon_data_test)
        Dll2_kaon_data_test = scaler_Dll.transform(Dll2_kaon_data_test)

        inputs_kaon_data_test = mapping(inputs_kaon_data_test)
        Dll_kaon_data_test = mapping(Dll_kaon_data_test)
        Dll2_kaon_data_test = mapping(Dll2_kaon_data_test)

        # Producing testing data
        params_list_test = np.random.normal(loc=mu, scale=sigma, size=[len(kaon_data_test), self.params])
        for e in range(len(kaon_data_test)):
            params_list_test[e][0] = inputs_kaon_data_test[e][0]
            params_list_test[e][1] = inputs_kaon_data_test[e][1]
            params_list_test[e][2] = inputs_kaon_data_test[e][2]
            params_list_test[e][3] = inputs_kaon_data_test[e][3]
            params_list_test[e][4] = inputs_kaon_data_test[e][4]
            params_list_test[e][5] = inputs_kaon_data_test[e][5]
            params_list_test[e][6] = inputs_kaon_data_test[e][6]
            params_list_test[e][7] = inputs_kaon_data_test[e][7]
            params_list_test[e][8] = inputs_kaon_data_test[e][8]
            params_list_test[e][9] = inputs_kaon_data_test[e][9]
            params_list_test[e][10] = inputs_kaon_data_test[e][10]
            params_list_test[e][11] = inputs_kaon_data_test[e][11]
            params_list_test[e][12] = inputs_kaon_data_test[e][12]

        obs_simu_1_test = np.zeros((len(kaon_data_test), self.observables, 1))
        obs_simu_1_test.fill(-1)
        for e in range(len(kaon_data_test)):
            obs_simu_1_test[e][0][0] = Dll_kaon_data_test[e][0]
            obs_simu_1_test[e][1][0] = Dll_kaon_data_test[e][1]
            obs_simu_1_test[e][2][0] = Dll_kaon_data_test[e][2]
            obs_simu_1_test[e][3][0] = Dll_kaon_data_test[e][3]
            obs_simu_1_test[e][4][0] = Dll_kaon_data_test[e][4]
            obs_simu_1_test[e][5][0] = Dll_kaon_data_test[e][5]

        obs_simu_2_test = np.zeros((len(kaon_data_test), self.observables, 1))
        obs_simu_2_test.fill(-1)
        for e in range(len(kaon_data_test)):
            obs_simu_2_test[e][0][0] = Dll2_kaon_data_test[e][0]
            obs_simu_2_test[e][1][0] = Dll2_kaon_data_test[e][1]
            obs_simu_2_test[e][2][0] = Dll2_kaon_data_test[e][2]
            obs_simu_2_test[e][3][0] = Dll2_kaon_data_test[e][3]
            obs_simu_2_test[e][4][0] = Dll2_kaon_data_test[e][4]
            obs_simu_2_test[e][5][0] = Dll2_kaon_data_test[e][5]

        event_no_par = 0
        event_no_obs_1 = 0
        event_no_obs_2 = 0

        d1_hist, d2_hist, d_hist, g_hist, a1_hist, a2_hist = list(), list(), list(), list(), list(), list()

        print('Beginning pre-training...')
        '''
        #Pre-training stage
        '''
        for train_step in range(pretrain_steps):
            log_mesg = '%d' % train_step
            noise_value = 0.3
            params_list = np.random.normal(loc=mu,scale=sigma, size=[batch_size, self.params])
            y_ones = np.ones([batch_size, 1])
            y_zeros = np.zeros([batch_size, 1])

            # add physics parameters + noise to params_list

            for b in range(batch_size):
                params_list[b][0] = inputs_kaon_data_train[event_no_par][0]
                params_list[b][1] = inputs_kaon_data_train[event_no_par][1]
                params_list[b][2] = inputs_kaon_data_train[event_no_par][2]
                params_list[b][3] = inputs_kaon_data_train[event_no_par][3]
                params_list[b][4] = inputs_kaon_data_train[event_no_par][4]
                params_list[b][5] = inputs_kaon_data_train[event_no_par][5]
                params_list[b][6] = inputs_kaon_data_train[event_no_par][6]
                params_list[b][7] = inputs_kaon_data_train[event_no_par][7]
                params_list[b][8] = inputs_kaon_data_train[event_no_par][8]
                params_list[b][9] = inputs_kaon_data_train[event_no_par][9]
                params_list[b][10] = inputs_kaon_data_train[event_no_par][10]
                params_list[b][11] = inputs_kaon_data_train[event_no_par][11]
                params_list[b][12] = inputs_kaon_data_train[event_no_par][12]
                event_no_par += 1

            # Step 1
            # simulated observables (number 1)
            obs_simu_1 = np.zeros((batch_size, self.observables, 1))
            obs_simu_1.fill(-1)
            for b in range(batch_size):
                obs_simu_1[b][0][0] = Dll_kaon_data_train[event_no_obs_1][0]
                obs_simu_1[b][1][0] = Dll_kaon_data_train[event_no_obs_1][1]
                obs_simu_1[b][2][0] = Dll_kaon_data_train[event_no_obs_1][2]
                obs_simu_1[b][3][0] = Dll_kaon_data_train[event_no_obs_1][3]
                obs_simu_1[b][4][0] = Dll_kaon_data_train[event_no_obs_1][4]
                obs_simu_1[b][5][0] = Dll_kaon_data_train[event_no_obs_1][5]
                event_no_obs_1 += 1

            obs_simu_1_copy = np.copy(obs_simu_1)

            # simulated observables (Gaussian smeared - number 2)
            obs_simu_2 = np.zeros((batch_size, self.observables, 1))
            obs_simu_2.fill(-1)
            for b in range(batch_size):
                obs_simu_2[b][0][0] = Dll2_kaon_data_train[event_no_obs_2][0]
                obs_simu_2[b][1][0] = Dll2_kaon_data_train[event_no_obs_2][1]
                obs_simu_2[b][2][0] = Dll2_kaon_data_train[event_no_obs_2][2]
                obs_simu_2[b][3][0] = Dll2_kaon_data_train[event_no_obs_2][3]
                obs_simu_2[b][4][0] = Dll2_kaon_data_train[event_no_obs_2][4]
                obs_simu_2[b][5][0] = Dll2_kaon_data_train[event_no_obs_2][5]
                event_no_obs_2 += 1

            obs_simu_2_copy = np.copy(obs_simu_2)

            # emulated DLL values
            obs_emul = self.emulator.predict(params_list)
            obs_emul_copy = np.copy(obs_emul)

            # decay the learn rate
            if(train_step % 1000 == 0 and train_step>0):
                siamese_lr = K.eval(self.siamese.optimizer.lr)
                K.set_value(self.siamese.optimizer.lr, siamese_lr*0.7)
                print('lr for Siamese network updated from %f to %f' % (siamese_lr, siamese_lr*0.7))
                adversarial1_lr = K.eval(self.adversarial1.optimizer.lr)
                K.set_value(self.adversarial1.optimizer.lr, adversarial1_lr*0.7)
                print('lr for Adversarial1 network updated from %f to %f' % (adversarial1_lr, adversarial1_lr*0.7))

            loss_simu_list = [obs_simu_1_copy, obs_simu_2_copy]
            loss_fake_list = [obs_simu_1_copy, obs_emul_copy]

            input_val = 0
            # swap which inputs to give to Siamese network
            if(np.random.random() < 0.5):
                loss_simu_list[0], loss_simu_list[1] = loss_simu_list[1], loss_simu_list[0]

            if(np.random.random() < 0.5):
                loss_fake_list[0] = obs_simu_2_copy
                input_val = 1

            # noise
            y_ones = np.array([np.random.uniform(0.97, 1.00) for x in range(batch_size)]).reshape([batch_size, 1])
            y_zeros = np.array([np.random.uniform(0.00, 0.03) for x in range(batch_size)]).reshape([batch_size, 1])

            if(input_val == 0):
                if np.random.random() < noise_value:
                    for b in range(batch_size):
                        if np.random.random() < noise_value:
                            obs_simu_1_copy[b], obs_simu_2_copy[b] = obs_simu_2[b], obs_simu_1[b]
                            obs_simu_1_copy[b], obs_emul_copy[b] = obs_emul[b], obs_simu_1[b]

            if(input_val == 1):
                if np.random.random() < noise_value:
                    for b in range(batch_size):
                        if np.random.random() < noise_value:
                            obs_simu_1_copy[b], obs_simu_2_copy[b] = obs_simu_2[b], obs_simu_1[b]
                            obs_simu_2_copy[b], obs_emul_copy[b] = obs_emul[b], obs_simu_2[b]

            # train siamese
            d_loss_simu = self.siamese.train_on_batch(loss_simu_list, y_ones)
            d_loss_fake = self.siamese.train_on_batch(loss_fake_list, y_zeros)
            d_loss = 0.5 * np.add(d_loss_simu, d_loss_fake)
            log_mesg = '%s [S loss: %f]' % (log_mesg, d_loss[0])

            #print(log_mesg)
            #print('--------------------')

            #noise_value*=0.999

            #Step 2

            # train emulator

            a_loss_list = [obs_simu_1, params_list]


            a_loss = self.adversarial1.train_on_batch(a_loss_list, y_ones)
            log_mesg = '%s [E loss: %f]' % (log_mesg, a_loss[0])
            print(log_mesg)
            print('--------------------')

            noise_value*=0.999


if __name__ == '__main__':

    params_physics = 13
    params_noise = 51 #51 looks ok, 61 is probably best, 100 also works
    params = params_physics + params_noise
    observables= 6
    train_no = 1

    magan = ModelAssistedGANPID(params=params, observables=observables)
    magan.train(pretrain_steps=11001, train_steps=10000, batch_size=32, train_no=train_no)
```

NETWORKS

```
class Networks(object):
    def __init__(self, noise_size=100, params=64, observables=5):

        self.noise_size = noise_size
        self.params = params
        self.observables = observables

        self.E = None # emulator
        self.S = None # siamese
        self.SM = None # siamese model
        self.AM1 = None # adversarial model 1

'''
    Emulator: generate identical observable parameters to those of the simulator S when both E and S are fed with the same input parameters
    '''
    def emulator(self):
        if self.E:
            return self.E

        # input params
        # the model takes as input an array of shape (*, self.params = 6)
        input_params_shape = (self.params,)
        input_params_layer = Input(shape=input_params_shape, name='input_params')

        # architecture
        self.E = Dense(1024)(input_params_layer)
        self.E = LeakyReLU(0.2)(self.E)

        self.E = Dense(self.observables*128, kernel_initializer=initializers.RandomNormal(stddev=0.02))(self.E)
        self.E = LeakyReLU(0.2)(self.E)
        self.E = Reshape((self.observables, 128))(self.E)
        self.E = UpSampling1D(size=2)(self.E)
        self.E = Conv1D(64, kernel_size=7, padding='valid')(self.E)
        self.E = LeakyReLU(0.2)(self.E)
        self.E = UpSampling1D(size=2)(self.E)
        self.E = Conv1D(1, kernel_size=7, padding='valid', activation='tanh')(self.E)

        # model
        self.E = Model(inputs=input_params_layer, outputs=self.E, name='emulator')

        # print
        print("Emulator")
        self.E.summary()

        return self.E

    '''
    Siamese: determine the similarity between output values produced by the simulator and emulator
    '''
    def siamese(self):
        if self.S:
            return self.S

        # input DLL images
        input_shape = (self.observables, 1)
        input_layer_anchor = Input(shape=input_shape, name='input_layer_anchor')
        input_layer_candid = Input(shape=input_shape, name='input_layer_candidate')
        input_layer = Input(shape=input_shape, name='input_layer')

        # siamese
        cnn = Conv1D(64, kernel_size=8, strides=2, padding='same', 
                     kernel_initializer=initializers.RandomNormal(stddev=0.02))(input_layer)
        cnn = LeakyReLU(0.2)(cnn)
        cnn = Conv1D(128, kernel_size=5, strides=2, padding='same')(cnn)
        cnn = LeakyReLU(0.2)(cnn)
        cnn = Flatten()(cnn)
        cnn = Dense(128, activation='sigmoid')(cnn)
        cnn = Model(inputs=input_layer, outputs=cnn, name='cnn')

        # left and right encodings       
        encoded_l = cnn(input_layer_anchor)
        encoded_r = cnn(input_layer_candid)

        # merge two encoded inputs with the L1 or L2 distance between them
        L1_distance = lambda x: K.abs(x[0]-x[1])
        L2_distance = lambda x: (x[0]-x[1]+K.epsilon())**2/(x[0]+x[1]+K.epsilon())
        both = Lambda(L2_distance)([encoded_l, encoded_r])
        prediction = Dense(1, activation='sigmoid')(both)

        # model
        self.S = Model([input_layer_anchor, input_layer_candid], outputs=prediction, name='siamese')

        # print
        print("Siamese:")
        self.S.summary()
        print("Siamese CNN:")
        cnn.summary()

        return self.S

'''
    Siamese model
    '''
    def siamese_model(self):
        if self.SM:
            return self.SM

        # optimizer
        optimizer = Adam(lr=0.004, beta_1=0.5, beta_2=0.9)

        # input DLL values
        input_shape = (self.observables, 1)
        input_layer_anchor = Input(shape=input_shape, name='input_layer_anchor')
        input_layer_candid = Input(shape=input_shape, name='input_layer_candidate')
        input_layer = [input_layer_anchor, input_layer_candid]

        # discriminator
        siamese_ref = self.siamese()
        siamese_ref.trainable = True
        self.SM = siamese_ref(input_layer)

        # model
        self.SM = Model(inputs=input_layer, outputs=self.SM, name='siamese_model')
        self.SM.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', optimizer=optimizer, metrics=[metrics.binary_accuracy])

        print("Siamese model")
        self.SM.summary()

        return self.SM


    '''
    Adversarial 1 model (adversarial pre-training phase) - this is where the emulator and siamese network are trained to enable the emulator to generate DLL values for a set of given physics inputs
    '''
    def adversarial1_model(self):
        if self.AM1:
            return self.AM1

        optimizer = Adam(lr=0.0004, beta_1=0.5, beta_2=0.9)

        # input 1: simulated DLL values
        input_obs_shape = (self.observables, 1)
        input_obs_layer = Input(shape=input_obs_shape, name='input_obs')

        # input 2: params
        input_params_shape = (self.params, )
        input_params_layer = Input(shape=input_params_shape, name='input_params')

        # emulator
        emulator_ref = self.emulator()
        emulator_ref.trainable = True
        self.AM1 = emulator_ref(input_params_layer)

        # siamese
        siamese_ref = self.siamese()
        siamese_ref.trainable = False
        self.AM1 = siamese_ref([input_obs_layer, self.AM1])

        # model
        input_layer = [input_obs_layer, input_params_layer]
        self.AM1 = Model(inputs=input_layer, outputs=self.AM1, name='adversarial_1_model')
        self.AM1.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', optimizer=optimizer, metrics=[metrics.binary_accuracy])

        # print
        print("Adversarial 1 model:")
        self.AM1.summary()

        return self.AM1
```

INPUTS PLOT
[image: Inputs Plot]
OUTPUTS PLOT
[image: Outputs Plot]
LOSS PLOT
[image: Loss plot]
GENERATED OUTPUT (ORANGE) vs TRUE OUTPUT (BLUE)
[image: Output Comparison Plot]